# Absolutely positioned flex item is not removed from the normal flow in IE11

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

We have two divs with content and a third div that is a background with absolute position.

Container is a flexbox.

All works fine in Chrome and Safari, but <s>Firefox and</s> IE11 factors in the absolute positioned div, and distributes space between divs like there are 3 divs in a row.

[image]

I've made jsfiddle example. Is there any way to fix this bug?
https://jsfiddle.net/s18do03e/2/

```css
div.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  outline: 1px solid;
}
div.c1 {
  background: #aaeecc;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 50;
  top: 20px;
  display: flex;
}
div.c2 {
  background: #cceeaa;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 50;
  top: 20px;
  display: flex;
}
div.bg {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="c1">Content 1</div>
  <div class="c2">Content 2</div>
  <div class="bg">Background</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Absolute positioning inside flex-container as of dec. 2019: https://codepen.io/ekadagami/pen/mdyPybq

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is happening because `justify-content: space-between;` Distribute items evenly The first item at the start, the last at the end. So just putt `<div class="bg">Background</div>` between `<div class="c1">Content 1</div>` and  `<div class="c2">Content 2</div>`
 like  this

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="c1">Content 1</div>
    <div class="bg">Background</div>
    <div class="c2">Content 2</div>

</div>
```

You can see the reason on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content

Answer (score 37):

**UPDATE:** This issue has been resolved in Firefox (as of v52, released March 2017). The problem still exists in IE11.

---

Like you wrote in the question:

> Firefox calculates absolute positioned div, and distributes space between divs like there are 3 divs in a row.

Firefox is considering the third div (`.bg`), which is absolutely positioned, an *in-flow* flex item and factoring it into its `space-between` calculation. (IE11 does this, too; Chrome and Edge ignore it.)

Clearly, this is not in compliance with the current flexbox spec:

> [**4.1. Absolutely-Positioned Flex Children**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#abspos-items)
>
> As it is out-of-flow, an absolutely-positioned child of a flex
>   container does not participate in flex layout.

Here are some workarounds:

***Why not move the absolutely positioned div between the other two?***

Instead of this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="c1">Content 1</div>
    <div class="c2">Content 2</div>
    <div class="bg">Background</div>
</div>
```

Try this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="c1">Content 1</div>
    <div class="bg">Background</div>
    <div class="c2">Content 2</div>
</div>
```

```css
div.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  outline: 1px solid;
}
div.c1 {
  background: #aaeecc;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 50;
  top: 20px;
  display: flex;
}
div.c2 {
  background: #cceeaa;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 50;
  top: 20px;
  display: flex;
}
div.bg {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="c1">Content 1</div>
  <div class="bg">Background</div>
  <div class="c2">Content 2</div>
</div>
```

***OR... remove `.bg` from the flex container:***

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="c1">Content 1</div>
    <div class="c2">Content 2</div>
</div>
<div class="bg">Background</div>
```

```css
div.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  outline: 1px solid;
}
div.c1 {
  background: #aaeecc;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 50;
  top: 20px;
  display: flex;
}
div.c2 {
  background: #cceeaa;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 50;
  top: 20px;
  display: flex;
}
div.bg {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="c1">Content 1</div>
  <div class="c2">Content 2</div>
</div>
<div class="bg">Background</div>
```

***OR... use the flex `order` property to re-arrange the flex items.***

Add this to your code:

```
.c2 { order: 1; }
```

```css
div.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  outline: 1px solid;
}
div.c1 {
  background: #aaeecc;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 50;
  top: 20px;
  display: flex;
}
div.c2 {
  background: #cceeaa;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 50;
  top: 20px;
  display: flex;
  order: 1;
}
div.bg {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="c1">Content 1</div>
  <div class="c2">Content 2</div>
  <div class="bg">Background</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is an incredibly thorough answer. Spot on mate.

Comment: Note that Firefox (and IE) have this behavior because it was [required by an older revision of the flexbox spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-flexbox-20120612/#abspos-flex-items) -- the spec text on abspos flex children has changed quite a bit over time. Good news, though -- the current spec behavior [will](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1269045) [ship](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1269046) in Firefox 52! (which is slated for release on March 7th 2017)

Comment: Well done and best answer here. I'd suggest using the "order" property before the other suggestions as this is really a CSS question, and source ordering a background div last is better and removing it from the container might not be possible.

Comment: What is `order` doing here exactly?

Comment: It's moving the `.c2` element, which is second in the source, to the third position ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36118012/3597276)). @DrazenBjelovuk

Comment: Hmm, does this only work with 3 elements? I'm trying to replicate the fix in a similar scenario with 5, but it still seems to take up space in IE (even when all together moving it into the center).

Comment: In any case, moving it out seems the way to go for me anyway as my component houses a variable number of flex-items wherein ensuring the order in all cases appears beyond the limits of css.

Comment: [The default `order` value is `0` for all flex items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector/36118012#36118012). If you change the value of one item to `1`, it puts it in last position (`-1` would put it in first position). If you want to move an item between other items, you would need to adjust the `order` value for all items (`1`, `2`, `3`, etc.), in order to shift them around. @DrazenBjelovuk

Comment: Yep I got that, the ordering was fine (like I said, still didn't seem to work after moving the element altogether, the extra space just shifted to the middle). But anyway, I've gone with the moving it out approach and that fits my needs fine. Great answer either way.

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes it is not possible to re-order stuff, for example when using `::before` and `::after`. In those cases, you can manually `order` the elements.

In your case, you would need to do:

```
.c1 {
  order: -1;
}
.c2 {
  order: 10;
}
```

The `order` property is part of the `flex` spec and lets you re-order flex items ([reference on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order)). It's very handy for multiple purposes, this included.

I used `-1` because the value is ordinal, so setting it to a negative number ensures it precedes all other defaults and you don't need to specify the value for `::before`. For the same reason, using `10` ensures that the second div comes last even if you add a bunch of elements to the container. You can increase that to `100` or whatever.

Still, Firefox's behaviour seems counterintuitive. `position: absolute` normally removes the element for the usual dom flow and I would expect that element to be removed from the `flex` flow as well, just like in Safari and Chrome. I am not sure whether the spec clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you can use the flex property inside the content selector(s):

```
    div.c1 {
      background: #aaeecc;
      width: 100px;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 50; top: 20px;
      display: flex;

      flex: 1; /* add this */
    }
```

This will set the flex-grow. It might not be exactly what you need, but maybe it helps somebody else that can not reorder the content divs or take them out from the flex wrapper.

Here is the demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/s18do03e/14/