# Exclude element with fixed positioning from justify-content in flex layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm currently trying to build a responsive website layout with flexbox.

Depending on the screen size I want an element to have `position: fixed;` This itself is working. But when I use `justify-content: space-between;` on a column that contains an element that gets moved out of the of column itself with `position: fixed;` the space distribution uses this element as an 0 height element.

For the sake of demonstration I set up two examples. Both do not use media queries because they are not the problem.

In the first example I created what I want the final result to look like. I had to move `#fixed` outside of `.column` in order for the space distribution to work properly.

In the second example I created the desired HTML markup. When you compare both example side by side you will notice that the spacing looks odd in the second. The browser is not making an error here because there is an element it has to respect when distributing the space. I (in a nutshell) would like the browser to pretend `#fixed` is not inside the container and therefore not consider it when distributing space.

This is how the result should look: https://jsfiddle.net/5nu9nsyL/3/

And this is how the html should look: https://jsfiddle.net/5nu9nsyL/4/
(Only Chrome and Safari renders it correctly. So if both look the same to you have a look at it with a different browser like Firefox or IE)

I hope I made my it clear what I want.

(Note I must use `display: flex` on the container `.column`)

(I also need a JavaScript free, CSS only solution)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want the space between items in the second column to be the same height as the space between items in the first column?

Comment: Exactly! That's what I want. (The second element has to still stay there in the markup)

Comment: I see what you're talking about. One issue to consider is the browser. In Chrome 47 and 48 both examples you posted render the same. The difference you mention exists in Firefox and IE11, but not Chrome.

Comment: I provided an answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32991051/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B Thank you. The problem is that need it to work for pretty much all (modern) browsers. Also I cannot change the order or postion of  the ``#fixed`` element. Mainly because in some screen sizes the element does not have the `position: fixed` properties (using media queries). But elaborating on that would be outside of the scope of this question

Comment: Well, as you can see, absolutely-positioned flex items are factored into the `space-between` calculation in some browsers. In particular, FF and IE11.

Comment: @Michael_B I noticed. I somehow need a fix for that...

Comment: If / When you find a solution, please post an answer here and a link to your answer [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32991051/3597276). Good luck.

Comment: @BrainStone In the new demo, there is only one column. Your objective was to maintain a space between ele1 and ele3 at the same length as col1. Has this changed? Also, I take it that you don't want any extra markup, hence the JS.

Comment: I did not make myself clear in the first place. I want an even distribution of the space between the elements in the container column.

Comment: Ok, so col1 is irrelevant and you have no intentions of placing element 2 back into the column. It's a Firefox/IE thing then, too bad.

Comment: Element will be placed back in the column on mobile browsers and small windows. But that's not relevant to the problem.

Comment: It may be worth noting for future reference that the container removes a flex item from the `space-between` calculation in FF/IE11 with `display: none`.

Comment: @Michael_B True but not helpful since all child elements of an element with `display: none` will not be visible. Otherwise this would have been the solution.

Comment: Right. I didn't think this would work for you, hence I posted for future reference.

Answer (score 10):

This is Firefox [bug 874718](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=874718). The [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#justify-content-property) says

> The [`justify-content`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-justify-content) property aligns [flex items](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-item) along the
>   [main axis](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#main-axis) of the current line of the flex container.

Since an absolutely (including fixedly) positioned element is out-of-flow, is not a [flex item](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-item) (this is fully defined in [Absolutely-Positioned Flex Children](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#abspos-items)). So `justify-content` should ignore it.

But Firefox wraps it inside an anonymous flex item, according to an [old spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-flexbox-20120612/#abspos-flex-items):

> Absolutely positioned children of a flex container are not themselves
>   flex items, but they leave behind "placeholders" in their normal
>   position in the box tree. These placeholders are anonymous inline
>   boxes with a width, height, and line-height of ‘0’, and they interact
>   normally with the flexbox layout algorithm. In particular, they'll
>   trigger the creation of anonymous flex items, or join neighboring
>   inline elements in their anonymous flex items.

To fix that, instead of using `justify-content`, I recommend [aligning with `auto` margins](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins):

```css
.column > div:not(:first-child) {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

That will distribute free space equally before the children of the flex container, except the first one. The effect should be like `justify-content: space-between`.

In the case of the fixed element, that `auto` margin will just compute to `0`.

```css
.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
.column > div:not(:first-child) {
  margin-top: auto;
}
.column > div,
#fixed {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
#fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <div>Element 1</div>
  <div id="fixed">Element 2</div>
  <div>Element 3</div>
  <div>Element 4</div>
  <div>Element 5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I never knew `margin: auto` works on vertical spacing as well. Is there a bug in the firefox bugtracker? If not I would recommend reporting it (if I knew how to either look up or report I would do it myself. But I don't know how to do either of these things)

Comment: @BrainStone `margin: auto` works vertically in flexbox, but not in block layout. The problem has been reported already in [bug 874718](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=874718).

Comment: Well, I'm fairly new to flexbox and this new to me. It seems like this bug won't be fixed soon so I guess I'll have to use your solution (as soon as I can confirm that it works on the actual site I'll accept it. I will check it monday or tuesday)

Answer (score 1):

## Update

Upon reviewing the OP once more, this is the objective:

When the screen width is at a certain size (I determined 720px+), `#fixed`(col2 ele2) is `position: fixed`, if it's at a smaller width, it will be `position: static`. When `#fixed` is "fixed" it is no longer in col2, therefore the spacing between col2's children increase. What is desired is a consistent spacing between all divs (ie col2 spacing must coincide with col1 spacing).

The OP did not provide a means to show both states: fixed and static; of which static needed to be established. I have added two media queries that will insure both static and fixed states of `#fixed` will be triggered at 720px.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 721px) {
  .spacer {
    display: none;
  }
  #fixed {
    position: fixed;
  }
  .column.column {
    justify-content: space-between !important;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  .spacer.spacer {
    display: none !important;
  }
  #fixed {
    position: static;
  }
  .column.column {
    justify-content: space-between !important;
  }
}
```

For some reason, when applying just the properties `display` and `position`, the `justify-content: space-between` would break. So I included `justify-content: space-between` to both media queries, unfortunately that didn't work either. So then I added `!important`, and it still failed. So then I used my secret ninja technique and doubled the class selector `.column.column` and I was victorious! Doubling up on a selector will increase it's specitivity to trump anything.

[**Plunker in Full Screen Mode**](http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/yvZq3xK89HY2GUcnHOVt/) Resize the browser to see the magic.

[**Plunker in Preview Mode**](http://plnkr.co/edit/yvZq3xK89HY2GUcnHOVt?p=preview)

---

<del>I don't understand what you want to with `#fixed`. But I do understand the problem described in the demo:</del>

> The space between Element 1 and Element 3 in the second column should be the same height as the other spaces.

Since the second column cannot arbitrarily space it's content by a predetermined length due to the nature of `justify-content: space-between`, you'll need just as many divs as the first column in order to obtain the same spacing as the first column. As I understand it, you cannot hard code layout (HTML), so I wrote a little JS to create an invisible div and append it to the second column thereby making the space between element 1 and 3 the same as the spaces between the children of the first column.

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/5nu9nsyL/2/)

Comment: No Javascript please. Also your example is not working (for me)  
Also see the updated question. I provided better examples