# Flexbox CSS Vertical Alignment not Completely Central

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've used flexbox before for vertical alignment, but for the elements I'm using it on at the moment the alignment is very off-centre, particularly for the div in the JSFiddle example below, where adding a button to the same div that contains the rest of the text is making the alignment too low.

Code:

```css
#servicesGrid {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.service {
  width: 24.85%;
  height: 45%;
  background: #262626;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0.2% 0 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#servicesGrid .service:nth-of-type(1) {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 0.2% 0;
  height: 80%;
}
#servicesGrid .service:nth-of-type(5) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.serviceContent {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
.button {
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Effra-Regular';
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all linear 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all linear 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all linear 0.3s;
}
.button:hover {
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="servicesGrid">
  <div class="service">
    <div class="serviceContent">
      <div style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto">
        <h1 style="font-size:40px; font-family:'Effra-Light'; margin-bottom:-10px">Service</h1>
        <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h4>
        <br/>
        <a href="#contactUs" class="button" alt="Find Out More Button">Find Out More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f92udw9v/2/.

Comment: Flex alignment works by distributing free space in the container. If you have a single item to center, that's not a problem. However, if you add a second item, that will create an imbalance. Now your centering is off because there is more "weight" on one side. You can either balance it out with a counter-weight or use absolute positioning. These methods are detailed here: [Absolute positioning in flexbox](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36191516/3597276).

Comment: You have various heights at 100%, 45% and 80% respectively. It's quite hard to understand what you're trying to achieve. Do you want it vertically centered within a div that is 80% of the screen height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few issues there:

1. Extra padding and margin (your button runs outside the .serviceContent).
2. The H1 at the top has a margin-top/bottom (probably user agent values) that distances it from the top of the .serviceContent.

Have a look at the [changes I made to your jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f92udw9v/2/).

```
          <div style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;border: 1px solid yellow;"> 

            <h1 style="font-size:40px; font-family:'Effra-Light';margin-top: 0px;">Service</h1>

            <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h4>

            </br>

            <a href="#contactUs" class="button" alt="Find Out More Button" style="display: inline-block;">Find Out More</a>

        </div>
```

What I did was:

1. Set the link () display to inline-block
2. Removed the top margin on H1

This still feels a bit of a hack to me, yet works slightly better. You might want to consider to using a column based flex box for the content (with the proper spacing) without element level margin/padding.