# Align one flex item to the end, while other items are centered

Tags: css, alignment, flexbox

This question has already been asked here:

[In CSS Flexbox, why are there no "justify-items" and "justify-self" properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551291/in-css-flexbox-why-are-there-no-justify-items-and-justify-self-properties)

However, the answer to that doesn't satisfy my particular problem:

Assuming the grey box is a flex container, I want to achieve this layout:

[image: flex items 1 and 2 aligned to the center, with flex-item 3 aligned to the end of the row]

The problem is if I use `margin-left: auto` on flex-item 3 I get this:

[image: flex items 1 and 2 aligned to the left, with flex-item 3 aligned to the end of the row]

Comment: The link you reference does indeed have an answer to your question (see box 66). You can also find an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36191516/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B You are fast ....

Comment: @vals, OP was referring to an answer I previously posted, so I was familiar ;-)

Comment: Thanks, it took me a while but I see now how that particular example applies. I do think that using `margin: auto` feels a bit hacky... but I understand some of the reasoning behind leaving `justify-self` out of the final spec due to the fact that the main axis can have multiple rows.