# Flexbox centering div1 vertically and horizontally, centering div2 horizontally at bottom of the parent div.

Tags: html, css, flexbox

`div.one` and `div.two` are inside `div.wrap`. I want to center `div.one` vertically and horizontally, also center `div.two` horizontally at the bottom of `div.wrap`. I can use `table` for it, but feeling like Flexbox is a better way.

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="one box">one</div>
  <div class="two box">two</div>
</div>


 .wrap {
   border:1px solid gray;
   padding: 30px;
   height: 300px;
   width: 100%;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
 }

 .one {
   padding: 10px;
   border: 1px solid red;
 }

 .two {
   padding: 10px;
   border: 1px solid red;
   align-self: flex-end;
 }
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hckcxkxm/)

Comment: Is [**this**](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/05v0kfao/) what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I think it is, you should read [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551291/in-css-flexbox-why-are-there-no-justify-items-and-justify-self-properties/33856609).

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I thought I tried this last night, didn't work. anyway, thanks man. And, thank you. I will read the link you sent.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36191516/3597276