# Unable to center flex item using align-self

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a simple layout requirement where I want to display a header and a logo as normal, and vertically center the content on the page.

To my understanding this should be easily achievable via flexbox using the `align-self` property.

Here is my code:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.base {
  display: flex;
  align-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
.header {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background: yellow;
}
.logo {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: orange;
}
.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  align-self: center; /* <<< DOESN"T SEEM TO WORK */
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="base">
  <div class="header">HEADER</div>
  <div class="logo">LOGO</div>
  <div class="content">CONTENT</div>
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m4qL824u/4/)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `align-self` property is closely related to `align-items`. One is designed to override the other. Hence, [they both function together](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-items-property).

However, `align-self` and `align-items` are meant primarily for use in a ***single-line flex container*** (i.e., `flex-wrap: nowrap`).

When you're working in a ***multi-line flex container*** (i.e., `flex-wrap: wrap`) – like in the question – the property to use is [`align-content`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-content-property).

But when `align-content` is in effect, both `align-items` and `align-self` are overridden.

> Therefore, the `align-self` rule applied to your `.content` element is being ignored because there are multiple lines in your flex container.

One possible solution to the problem is to switch the container from `row` to `column`, then use `auto` margins on `.content`:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.base {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
base > * {
  width: 100%;
}
.header {
  height: 30px;
  background: yellow;
}
.logo {
  height: 50px;
  background: orange;
}
.content {
  margin: auto 0;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="base">
  <div class="header">HEADER</div>
  <div class="logo">LOGO</div>
  <div class="content">CONTENT</div>
</div>
```

[**revised fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/m4qL824u/5/)

Just note that the solution above vertically centers the content element in the *remaining space*, not the *total space* in the container.

To center the element in the total space, see this post: [Center and bottom-align flex items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36191516/3597276)

For more about `auto` margins, see this post: [In CSS Flexbox, why are there no "justify-items" and "justify-self" properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276)

Answer (score 0):

Align self works respect the current line where the flex item is.

So, if you want the element to be centered in the flex-container, there must be only one line (in your case, only one row)

The snippet shows how this works, even though it's not a solution to your problem:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.base { 
  display: flex;
  align-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: blue;
}

.header {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 30%;
  height: 30px;
  background: yellow;
}

.logo {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 30%;
  height: 50px;
  background: orange;
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 30%;
  align-self: center; /* <<< DOESN"T SEEM TO WORK */
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="base">
  <div class="header">HEADER</div>
  <div class="logo">LOGO</div>
  <div class="content">CONTENT</div>
</div>
```