# Is there a way to change the alignment of the last element in a flex-box?

Tags: css, flexbox

So I have a container with `display:flex`. It contains elements which are centered justified. Is there a way to justify the last element to `start`? I tried `align-self: start` It didn't work.

```css
.main{
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.child{
  width: 90px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.child:last-child{
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="child">
    1
  </div>
   <div class="child">
    1
  </div>
   <div class="child">
    1
  </div>
   <div class="child">
    1
  </div>
   <div class="child">
    1
  </div>
   <div class="child">
    1
  </div>
   <div class="child">
    1
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: `.child:last-child { margin-right: auto; }`

Comment: @j08691 Oh yeah, I forgot. `margin-left/right: auto` totally works for the last element in flex. Btw do you know the reason why `align-self` doesn't work. Thought that was the whole purpose pf this property.

Comment: Ok I found this answer explains why: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40725870/4650975