# align multiple flexbox items differently

Tags: css, alignment, flexbox

I have a div with two items in it. I put them in a column an needed the first item to justify: center and the second one to justify: flex-end. How do I do this?

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper wrapper--login">
   <h1 class="wrapper--login__title">
      Demo or Die
   </h1>
   <a class="btn wrapper--login__btn" href="#">
      Log in
   </a>
</div>
```

css:

```
.wrapper--login{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Comment: @LGSon i mean vertical

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The wrapper need a height and the title `margin: auto 0`

Note, this will center the item in the *available space* left (container *minus* bottom element), not in the center of the container.

To center it relative to the container, check these posts:

- [center-and-bottom-align-flex-items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36191516/center-and-bottom-align-flex-items)
- [center-and-right-align-flexbox-elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38948102/center-and-right-align-flexbox-elements)

```css
.wrapper--login{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  height: 200px;
}

.wrapper--login__title {
  margin: auto 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper wrapper--login">
   <h1 class="wrapper--login__title">
      Demo or Die
   </h1>
   <a class="btn wrapper--login__btn" href="#">
      Log in
   </a>
</div>
```