# Bootstrap 4 Vertically center a row within d-flex container-fluid

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I'm trying implement a component with Bootstrap 4 that looks something like this:

```
+-------------------------+
| Row 1 - Top             |
+-------------------------+
|                         |
|                         |
+-------------------------+
| Row 2 - Vertical Center |
+-------------------------+
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
+-------------------------+
```

The height of the container is supposed to be 100vh.
According to my understanding, using flex would be an approach to solve this problem.

This is the markup I currently have: http://codeply.com/go/RRMwIHt8QA

As you can see, there seems to be some kind of offset of Row 2. Any ideas what's causing this and how to make the row take the full width of the available space?

Comment: Related if not dupe - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36191516/center-and-bottom-align-flex-items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish that you first need to add `flex-column` to the `container` so the `row`'s stack vertically.

Then the `row`'s need `align-items-start align-content-start` to prevent them from stretching.

Finally, using a pseudo, here `::after`, you can match the first `row` so the second `row` can be vertically centered. An alternative is to position the first `row` absolute, though I find the pseudo version more responsive.

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qeg1r748/)

Stack snippet

```css
.test-container {
  height: 100vh;
}
.test-container .row:first-child,
.test-container::after {
  content: '';
  flex: 1 1 0;
}

/* styling for this demo */
.test-container .row > div {
  border: 1px dashed lightgray;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="d-flex flex-column container-fluid test-container">
  <div class="row align-items-start align-content-start">
    <div class="col-4">R1-C1</div>
    <div class="col-4">R1-C2</div>
    <div class="col-4">R1-C3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row align-items-start align-content-start">
    <div class="col-4">R2-C1</div>
    <div class="col-4">R2-C2</div>
    <div class="col-4">R2-C3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

It's the  **d-flex** class that give you problems

Remove it or check [here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/) what better fits your needs