# Position a div in the space between two divs one inside the other

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image]

I have `div-1` which contains `div-2` and a heading inside. The size of `div-2` varies. I want the HEADING to be correctly between the top of the two divs as shown in the picture, with different sizes of `div-2`. Would love to have it in pure css or scss. I have centered the `div2` in `div1` using 
    `top: 50%; 
    left: 50% 
    transform = translate (-50%, -50%)`

but i can't center the 'heading' between the two 'divs'

I do not know the size of `div-2`. It keeps varying and I want the heading to be in the middle, unlike in the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36191516/center-and-bottom-align-flex-items) where the size of the elements is known.

Comment: What have you tried? We are not here to make your homework (With your level, I guess you know that xD).

Comment: I guess the HEADING is a nav or div, so try to style it with "width:100%" and as a simple block. With this the div2 will always under the HEADING.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález I know. :) The heading is another `div` but how do you vary the size of the `div` containing the heading to match the size between the two `divs`? You can't get the size of `div-2` otherwise we could've had calculated it using sass. I believe I've tried everything I know.

Comment: @DiabloSteve I don't want div2 under HEADING. I want `HEADING` to match the size between `div1` and `div2` and also `div2` to be at exact center of `div1`

Comment: This is not a duplicate because i do not know the size of `div2`.

Answer (score -2):

It is better to use flexbox for this, div1 you put `display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center; justify-content: center;`

Heading can be positioned absolute inside the div2 (position:relative), just set top value to -100px(example).

EDIT: However if you need the heading to be exactly in the middle, you need to use javascript to calculate the heights of these elements... (div1 - div2) / 2 = top space. So then top space - font size/2 is margin top of heading... hope you get it

Comment: I want the `heading` to be in the exact center not `-100px`

Comment: @illiteratewriter you will need javascript for this