# flexbox align items shifted from center without fillers

Tags: css, flexbox

Centering a flex item is easy. However I like to shift it upwards a bit so that the the relation between the upper and lower space is e. g. 1/2. Easy too when using fillers. But is there a way to do this whithout fillers?
HTML:

```
<div id="filler-top"></div>
<div id="the-item">
</div>
<div id="filler-bottom"></div>
```

CSS:

```
    #the-item {
        width: 80vw;
        height: 30vh;
        border: 2px solid lightblue;
      }
      body {
        height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
      }
      #filler-top {
        width: 100%;
        flex: 1;
      }
      #filler-bottom {
        width: 100%;
        flex: 2;
      }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Sempervivum/b2wotc8e/3/

Applying margin-top and margin-bottom doesn't work as a percentage is relative to the width.

Comment: instead of adding 2 elements to the markup, you can use `body:before` and `body:after`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36191516/3597276

Answer (score 0):

instead of adding 2 elements to the markup, you can use `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements:

```css
#the-item {
  width: 80vw;
  height: 30vh;
  border: 2px solid lightblue;
}
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
body:before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}
body:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  flex: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="the-item"></div>
```

Another option is to simply use a mixture of `position:relative`, `top` and `transform`:

```css
#the-item {
  width: 80vw;
  height: 30vh;
  border: 2px solid lightblue;
  position: relative;
  top: 33.333%;
  transform: translateY(-33.333%);
}
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div id="the-item"></div>
```