# Flexbox column vertical align a child at the top and a child at the center of the column

Tags: css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

Currently I'm struggling with flexbox column. Checked so many websites, but still no solutions to be found on the internet for this problem.

The case:
On the right side of my viewport I've got a full-height flex-column, containing 2 elements (see headset icon and hangup button). I used flex-column to vertically align my elements.
The first element should be on the top right corner, the second element should be at the center right. 
Since it's a flex-column I can't use align-self-center on the second element, because it will be centering on the x-axis instead of the y-axis.

I was wondering if this is even solvable with just flexbox or if I need to position this centered element a different way?

I'm using the bootstrap 4 flex classes to apply flexbox.

Code example: https://jsfiddle.net/mv1e7py0/18/

```
<div class="flex-container flex-column main-containere video-container">
  <div class="communication-controls d-flex justify-content-between">
    <div class="left-controls d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
      <button class="chat-toggle">
        Chat
        <div class="indicator bg-red"></div>
      </button>

      <button class="mic-toggle">
        Mic
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="right-controls d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
      <button class="speaker-toggle">
        Headset
      </button>

      <button class="dismiss-call red align-self-center">
        <span>Hang up</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want it to look like:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36191516/3597276

Comment: This doesn't look like the same issue as I'm describing

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: Code has been added

Answer (score 0):

@miranda-breekweg here are 2 quick solutions that I hope you'll find helpful:

In both cases we'll keep `justify-content` set to `space-between`.

1. the first thing that comes to mind is to simply set the height of the right column to 50% (+ half the height of that button you want to center)

   ```
   .right-controls {
     height: calc(50% + /half the height of your button/);
   }
   ```
2. the second and probably the easiest solution is to simply add auto margins (top and bottom) to the targeted button. This way, you don't have to worry about calculations:

   ```
   .dismiss-call {
     margin: auto 0;
   }
   ```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mv1e7py0/39/