# Flexbox not working properly with Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox

On Chrome, the `flexbox` keeps the body of the page vertically centered on the page. However, on firefox, the page is not vertically centered and all of the content is moved as far to the top of the page as possible which can be seen in the picture and codepen below.

*Firefox:* **not working** https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPhS3.jpg

*Chrome* **working** https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuKaJ.jpg

*Example of problem:* https://codepen.io/robbyjm/pen/PLeQVY?

```css
html {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  font-family: interstate-mono, monospace;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}

html body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

html body main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

html body main .weather-nav {
  display: flex;
}

html body main .weather-nav .weather {
  text-align: center;
}

html body main form {
  margin: 1em auto !important;
  height: 45px;
  width: 490px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
}

html body main form input[type="search"] {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 0.75em;
  border-width: 0;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-family: interstate-mono, monospace !important;
  font-weight: 300 !important;
  font-style: normal !important;
}

html body main form input[type="search"]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

html body main nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

html body main nav .bookmark-group {
  text-align: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-right: 2em;
}

html body main nav .bookmark-group hr {
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
}

html body main nav .bookmark {
  text-align: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
}

html body main nav .bookmark hr {
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
}

html body main nav .bookmark li {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 0.8em;
}

html body main nav .bookmark li a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

#stack {
  color: #f48024;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#git {
  color: #24292e;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#java {
  color: #467899;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#python {
  color: #467899;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#aws {
  color: #ec912d;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#nest {
  color: #aa253a;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#hs {
  color: #fece41;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#dw {
  color: #b30939;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#canvas {
  color: #9e1b32;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#waze {
  color: #85d5ea;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#yt {
  color: red;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#reddit {
  color: #ff4500;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#rd {
  color: silver;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#dayz {
  color: #292929;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#google {
  color: #1da362;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#mf {
  color: #0e2866;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#eye {
  color: #36393e;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#vim {
  color: navy;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#react {
  color: #61dafb;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#js {
  color: #f5f9fa;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#ct {
  color: #ff9800;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#bttn {
  color: #fffde7;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#animate {
  color: #7b8993;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="weather.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="bitcoin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/cnw4ewi.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <title>startpage</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <header></header>
  <main>
    <div class="weather-nav">
      <form action="https://duckduckgo.com/?q=" method="GET">
        <input type="search" name="q" placeholder=" welcome back" autoFocus></input>
      </form>
      <div class="weather">
        <div id="u"></div>
        <div id="t"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul class="bookmark-group">
        <li>dev</li>
        <hr>
        <li>social</li>
        <hr>
        <li>storage</li>
        <hr>
        <li>web</li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="bookmark">
        <li><a href="https://www.stackexchange.com"><span id="stack">[</span>Exchange<span id="stack">]</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.github.com/robbyjm"><span id="git">[</span>GitHub<span id="git">]</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/"><span id="dw">[</span>Ruby<span
                    id="dw">]</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/"><span id="java">[</span>Java<span id="java">]</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html"><span id="python">[</span>Python<span id="python">]</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://gist.github.com"><span id="git">[</span>Gist<span id="git">]</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://aws.amazon.com"><span id="aws">[</span>AWS<span id="aws">]</span></a></li>
        <hr>
        <li><a href="https://www.waze.com/livemap"><span id="waze">[</span>Waze<span id="waze">]</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com"><span id="yt">[</span>YouTube<span id="yt">]</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.reddit.com"><span id="reddit">[</span>Reddit<span id="reddit">]</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.yelp.com/"><span id="rd">[</span>Yelp<span id="rd">]</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://mail.tutanota.com/login"><span id="dayz">[</span>Tutanota<span id="dayz">]</span></a></li>
        <hr>
        <li><a href="https://drive.google.com"><span id="google">[</span>GoogleDrive<span id="google">]</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://mixtape.moe/"><span id="mf">[</span>M.Moe<span id="mf">]</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://the-eye.eu/"><span id="eye">[</span>TheEye<span id="eye">]</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://vimm.net/?p=vault"><span id="vim">[</span>Vimms<span id="vim">]</span></a></li>
        <hr>
        <li><a href="https://reactjs.org/"><span id="react">[</span>ReactJS<span id="react">]</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript"><span
                            id="java">[</span>JS<span id="java">]</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://css-tricks.com/"><span id="ct">[</span>CssTricks<span id="ct">]</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/"><span id="mdn">[</span>MDN<span id="mdn">]</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://bttn.surge.sh/"><span id="animate">[</span>Bttn<span id="animate">]</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/"><span id="animate">[</span>Animate<span id="animate">]</span></a></li>
        <br>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <div id="s"></div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: From your codepen, both chrome and firefox seem to behave same way where they are not vertically centered. 
Set height:100vh; to body.

Comment: @Jason `body {height: 100vh}` won't work because it's going to introduce a scroll bar to the page and push the footer off the page slightly

Comment: Set html {hieght: 100%} and body {margin:0; height:100%}. That seems to work in codePen. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LamdNq

Comment: @Jason yes it does! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `height: 100vh` on the `body` element. Then, to prevent a vertical scrollbar, override the default margins with `margin: 0`.

```
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100vh;  /* NEW */
  margin: 0;  /* NEW */
}
```

```css
html {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  font-family: interstate-mono, monospace;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100vh;  /* NEW */
  margin: 0;  /* NEW */
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.weather-nav {
  display: flex;
}

.weather {
  text-align: center;
}

main form {
  margin: 1em auto !important;
  height: 45px;
  width: 490px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
}

main form input[type="search"] {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 0.75em;
  border-width: 0;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-family: interstate-mono, monospace !important;
  font-weight: 300 !important;
  font-style: normal !important;
}

main form input[type="search"]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

main nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

main nav .bookmark-group {
  text-align: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-right: 2em;
}

main nav .bookmark-group hr {
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
}

main nav .bookmark {
  text-align: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
}

main nav .bookmark hr {
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
}

main nav .bookmark li {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 0.8em;
}

main nav .bookmark li a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

#stack {
  color: #f48024;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#git {
  color: #24292e;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#java {
  color: #467899;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#python {
  color: #467899;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#aws {
  color: #ec912d;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#nest {
  color: #aa253a;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#hs {
  color: #fece41;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#dw {
  color: #b30939;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#canvas {
  color: #9e1b32;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#waze {
  color: #85d5ea;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#yt {
  color: red;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#reddit {
  color: #ff4500;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#rd {
  color: silver;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#dayz {
  color: #292929;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#google {
  color: #1da362;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#mf {
  color: #0e2866;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#eye {
  color: #36393e;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#vim {
  color: navy;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#react {
  color: #61dafb;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#js {
  color: #f5f9fa;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#ct {
  color: #ff9800;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#bttn {
  color: #fffde7;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#animate {
  color: #7b8993;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<main>
  <div class="weather-nav">
    <form action="https://duckduckgo.com/?q=" method="GET">
      <input type="search" name="q" placeholder=" welcome back" autoFocus></input>
    </form>
    <div class="weather">
      <div id="u"></div>
      <div id="t"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <ul class="bookmark-group">
      <li>dev</li>
      <hr>
      <li>social</li>
      <hr>
      <li>storage</li>
      <hr>
      <li>web</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="bookmark">
      <li><a href="https://www.stackexchange.com"><span id="stack">[</span>Exchange<span id="stack">]</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.github.com/robbyjm"><span id="git">[</span>GitHub<span id="git">]</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/"><span id="dw">[</span>Ruby<span
                    id="dw">]</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/"><span id="java">[</span>Java<span id="java">]</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html"><span id="python">[</span>Python<span id="python">]</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://gist.github.com"><span id="git">[</span>Gist<span id="git">]</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://aws.amazon.com"><span id="aws">[</span>AWS<span id="aws">]</span></a></li>
      <hr>
      <li><a href="https://www.waze.com/livemap"><span id="waze">[</span>Waze<span id="waze">]</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com"><span id="yt">[</span>YouTube<span id="yt">]</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.reddit.com"><span id="reddit">[</span>Reddit<span id="reddit">]</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.yelp.com/"><span id="rd">[</span>Yelp<span id="rd">]</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://mail.tutanota.com/login"><span id="dayz">[</span>Tutanota<span id="dayz">]</span></a></li>
      <hr>
      <li><a href="https://drive.google.com"><span id="google">[</span>GoogleDrive<span id="google">]</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://mixtape.moe/"><span id="mf">[</span>M.Moe<span id="mf">]</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://the-eye.eu/"><span id="eye">[</span>TheEye<span id="eye">]</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://vimm.net/?p=vault"><span id="vim">[</span>Vimms<span id="vim">]</span></a></li>
      <hr>
      <li><a href="https://reactjs.org/"><span id="react">[</span>ReactJS<span id="react">]</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript"><span
                            id="java">[</span>JS<span id="java">]</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://css-tricks.com/"><span id="ct">[</span>CssTricks<span id="ct">]</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/"><span id="mdn">[</span>MDN<span id="mdn">]</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://bttn.surge.sh/"><span id="animate">[</span>Bttn<span id="animate">]</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/"><span id="animate">[</span>Animate<span id="animate">]</span></a></li>
      <br>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</main>
<footer>
  <div id="s"></div>
</footer>
```

---

Note that you're vertically centering the `main` element with `justify-content: space-between`. The element is thus centered on the page only because `header` and `footer` have equal heights (0px). However, once the header and footer grow, if they have differing heights, the `main` element will be thrown off center.

Full explanation and solutions here: [Center and bottom-align flex items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36191516/3597276)

---

Most browsers come with a [default `margin` on the `body` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/sample.html). It's usually 8px.

```
body { margin: 8px; }
```

This will often launch a vertical scrollbar when the `body` element is set to 100% height. To remove the overflow, simply override the default with:

```
body { margin: 0; }
```