# Aligning one item in the middle and next item right after using Flex CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

Sorry if the title is confusing.
I have the main container div with `display: flex`, `justify-content: center`, and `align-items: center`. Inside this div, I have another 2 divs, at the moment everything is centered, my issue is that I want the first div to be centered and the next div to be underneath (image). How can I accomplish this using flex?

[image]

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 500px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
.circle {
  width: 12rem;
  height: 12rem;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 9999px;
}
.square {
  width: 12rem;
  height: 6rem;
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: read the very long accepted answer and you will find what you want and more (scroll and look at the image and you will identify your case)

Comment: which leads also to that question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36191516/center-and-bottom-align-flex-items the hidden element can be generated via pseudo element if you do not want extra markup ;)