# Flexbox first element on center and the rest below

Tags: css, flexbox

There is a good chance someone has asked this question already, but I can't seem to figure out the right keywords to find the answer. I want my first element in a flexbox to be centered and the rest to align below it. Here's a picture of what I am trying to do.

[image]

```
<div style="justify-content:center; flex-direction: column;" >
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

is not what I am trying to achieve

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36191516/8620333

Answer (score 0):

For the center one div, use:

```css
justify-self: center;
```

And for the bottom ones, use:

```css
justify-self: flex-end;
```

Then you can position it with margins correctly

Comment: I don't think this will work. Align self only works on the cross-axis of the flexbox. So `align-self` will align the item horizontally, which is not what the question asked for.

Comment: @NHerwich Yea just realised. Justify-Self should work fine.

Comment: Justify-self doesn't work in flexbox.