How to horizontally align a specific flex item while others remain centered using CSS?
CSS Code Screenshot with example is here I have a container with the following CSS:
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.item-3 {
  align-self: flex-end;
}

Using the align-self property, I can move .item-3 vertically to the end. However, I also want to move it horizontally, for example, to the end, while keeping the other two items centered. Is there a specific property similar to align-self that can achieve this horizontal alignment for .item-3?
I tried using margin-left: auto but that is pushing away my centered items(item 1 and item 2).

Please [edit] your post to include [mre], preferably using the code snippet (<> in  the editor.)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36191516/center-and-bottom-align-flex-items

It's possible, but I don't think you need it. Use margin with the value auto on flex elements:


.items {
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1px;
  border: solid 1px;
  align-items: center;
}

.item {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: solid 1px;
}

.item-1 {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.item-3 {
  margin: auto 0 0 auto;
}
<div class="items">
  <div class="item item-1"></div>
  <div class="item item-2"></div>
  <div class="item item-3"></div>
</div>



