# Center span element under an image element (Ionic2)

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox, ionic2

How to centralize this span under the avatar using flex?

[image]

The avatar image is well centralized if I remove the span, but when I insert the span, even with `display:block` it displays on the right side.

Here is my **HTML**:

```
<ion-navbar *navbar>
    <ion-avatar item-center>
        <img src="img/bill-gates-avatar.jpg">
        <span>Bill Gates</span>
    </ion-avatar>
</ion-navbar>
<ion-content padding>
    Content here...
</ion-content>
```

That is my **SCSS**:

```
.tabs {

    ion-navbar-section {
        min-height: 16.6rem;
    }

    .toolbar {
        min-height: 170px;
    }

    ion-avatar {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-content: center;
    }

    ion-avatar img {
        max-width: 8rem;
        max-height: 8rem;
        border-radius: 5rem;
        border: 2px solid color($colors, light);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An initial setting of a flex container is `flex-direction: row`, meaning items will align horizontally by default. For vertical alignment, override the default with `flex-direction: column`.

```
ion-avatar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;    /* align flex items vertically */
    justify-content: center;   /* center items vertically, in this case */
    align-items: center;       /* center single-line items horizontally, in this case */
    align-content: center;     /* center multi-line items horizontally, in this case */
}
```

Note that when you switch `flex-direction`, keyword alignment properties such as `align-items` and `justify-content` switch direction, as well.

Alternatively, you can center the avatar by removing it from the normal flow with absolute positioning. However, in a flex container, [this may not work well in some browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32991051/3597276).

---

Learn more about flex alignment along the *main axis* here:

- [In CSS Flexbox, why are there no "justify-items" and "justify-self" properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276)

Learn more about flex alignment along the *cross axis* here:

- [How does flex-wrap work with align-self, align-items and align-content?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42613359/3597276)

Answer (score 1):

The Answer above is the best way to do it if you want vertical, and center positioning throughout the entire parent container, but if you want to style "bill gates" as a single child of the parent container, you can simply style him like...

```
.bill-gates{
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
}
```