# Absolute positionning: New Flexbox behavior in Chrome 53

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

I noticed a difference between Firefox and Chrome (from V53) with absolute positioning in a flex container

Chrome 53 act like we are using a `left: 0;` on the element.
Instead, the element should be positioned after the previous elements.

```css
body { background-color: #252525; color: #eee; }

.container { width: 100%; display: flex; flex-flow: row nowrap; background-color: grey; }

.static-content,
.absolute-content { display: flex; }

.static-content { flex: 0 0 auto; }
.absolute-content { flex: 1; background-color: tomato; position: absolute; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    
    <div class="container">

      <div class="static-content">
        Hello world!
      </div>

      <div class="absolute-content">
        Yo!
      </div>

    </div>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

How can i keep the Firefox behavior in the new version of Chrome?

Thanks!

Comment: Related? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32991051/why-is-an-absolutely-positioned-flex-item-not-being-ignored-by-justify-content

Comment: Use an extra container if this is an issue for you

Answer (score 0):

It works with an extra container.

```css
body { background-color: #252525; color: #eee; }

.container { width: 100%; display: flex; flex-flow: row nowrap; background-color: grey; }

.static-content,
.extra-container,
.absolute-content { display: flex; }

.static-content { flex: 0 0 auto; }
.absolute-content { flex: 1; background-color: tomato; position: absolute; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    
    <div class="container">

      <div class="static-content">
        Hello world!
      </div>

      <div class="extra-container">
        <div class="absolute-content">
          Yo!
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    
  </body>

</html>
```