# Disable space-around for one special div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image]There is part of css rules for parent div:

```
{
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 430px;
    background: #FFF none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    max-width: 750.5px;
    outline: medium none;
    float: right;
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -o-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: -webkit-row;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -moz-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    -o-flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    -webkit-flex-justify-content: space-around;
}
```

How to disable space-around for one child div? with following css:

```
.resultsDiv {
    position: absolute;
    top: 47px;
    left:0; 
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

As, I get idea, there should be something like justify-content-self: space-around

Comment: What do you mean by "disable space-around for one child div"? Can you give a visual example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I mean, that there is parent div(flexbox, button panel) with several elements, when I click on button, its create list, that have absolute position, under panel bar. But couse of spase around all list elements move left for 6 pixels. So I need to find solution how to disable space around for list div, to stop moving another elements, when list become visible.

Comment: Ok seriously. If there is a visual adjustment you want then please share a screenshot or a jsfiddle for us to help. Without detail we are unable to help.

Comment: Could you provide more details (screenshots, jsfiddles). Otherwise it is impossible to understand your question and provide an accurate answer

Comment: `position: absolute` does normally remove a flex item from the normal flow, and it should exclude your item from `justify-content: space-around`. Are you on Firefox by any chance? http://stackoverflow.com/q/32991051/3597276

Comment: Yes, Firefox.I add screenshot.left side part of control