# Display: flex and Position: absolute conflict

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox

Here's a [screenshot](http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2017/01/06/0001/0403/94611/11/ead09352f4.png)  of the problem.
To bottom: 1 - Chrome, 2 - Opera, 3 - Firefox, 4 - Edge.

Below I have written executable code.
For convenience, here [codepen](http://codepen.io/VostokSisters/pen/RKPrvE).

The basic idea: *Gallery* label and logo in the center position, and the rest - on the sides.
`Transform` will be used for animation.

Beyond measure I am grateful if you help to understand how to maintain flex in Firefox.
More precisely, I think that `align-items: center` is not correctly displayed in Firefox. Please help.

```css
.gallerypage {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #fff;
}

.gallerypage .header {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
      -ms-flex-flow: row nowrap;
          flex-flow: row nowrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
}

.gallerypage .header a {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
      -ms-flex-negative: 0;
          flex-shrink: 0;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  text-indent: -6px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-family: "Kaushan Script", cursive;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.gallerypage .header .sketches {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 110px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-400px, 0px);
      -ms-transform: translate(-400px, 0px);
          transform: translate(-400px, 0px);
}

.gallerypage .header .smth {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 140px;
  height: 60px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-200px, 0px);
      -ms-transform: translate(-200px, 0px);
          transform: translate(-200px, 0px);
}

.gallerypage .header .gallery {
  position: static;
  text-indent: -14px;
  line-height: normal;
  width: 185px;
  height: 90px;
  background: gold;
  font-size: 60px;
}

.gallerypage .header .logo {
  position: static;
  width: 60px;
  height: 80px;
  background: hotpink;
}

.gallerypage .header .logo .vs-logo {
  display: block;
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
      -ms-flex-negative: 0;
          flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 60px;
  height: 80px;
}

.gallerypage .header .blog {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 60px;
  height: 38px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(200px, 0px);
      -ms-transform: translate(200px, 0px);
          transform: translate(200px, 0px);
}

.gallerypage .header .about {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(400px, 0px);
      -ms-transform: translate(400px, 0px);
          transform: translate(400px, 0px);
}
```

```html
<div class="gallerypage">
  <div class="header">
    <a class="sketches">Sketches</a>
    <a class="smth">Something serious</a>
    <a class="gallery">Gallery</a><a class="logo"></a>
    <a class="blog">Blog</a><a class="about">About it</a>
  </div>
/<div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate: [Absolutely positioned flex item not being removed from normal flow in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32991051/3597276)

Comment: related: [Absolute positioning in flexbox](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36191516/3597276)

Comment: @Michael_B, no, here's another problem.

Comment: @VostokSisters, I think it is the same problem. Because your absolutely-positioned flex items are not removed from the normal flow in Firefox, they will align differently than in other browsers, where absolute positioning works as expected.

Comment: @Michael_B, I know about `justify-content: space-around;`, it's not what I looking for :)

Comment: That's not what I'm talking about. *In Firefox, absolutely positioned flex items ARE NOT removed from the document flow.* This means they are still considered in-flow flex items and take up space in the container. This will result in a different layout than in Chrome and other browsers.

Comment: @Michael_B, Yes, this is the cause. But knowing this, I still do not understand how to solve my problem ...

Comment: @Michael_B, Can you upgrade my [codepen](http://codepen.io/VostokSisters/pen/RKPrvE?editors=1100), please? I do not know how to solve it then.

Comment: The layout is not a problem. It's the animations that might take some time. Hopefully somebody else can help you. Otherwise, I'll come back after work and give it a shot.

Comment: It seems that the current behavior of Chrome is against the Flexbox spec, the latest version of which says that `align/justify-items` of the flex container shouldn't affect the position of abspos children: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=874718#c29

Comment: @Michael_B, thanks a lot! I already have a few ideas thanks to you, which I hope will help solve this problem

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to center the items with absolute positioning and `auto` margins only, without flexbox-related difficuilties, e.g. like http://codepen.io/SelenIT/pen/LxVxYP ?

Comment: @VostokSisters, just to clarify, all you want to fix in your code is the vertical alignment of the 4 side items right?

Comment: @AliAbdelfattah, yeah,right,  just this 4 side items do not correctly displayed in Firefox...

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn, While there was no answer, I got almost exactly the same  [solution](http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2017/01/06/0001/0403/94611/11/c982533d97.png)! Without the use of flex. Later I will add my decision in the answers. Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both vertical and horizontal alignment issues are resolved in Firefox. I've also applied a simple animation to make sure it's compatible with what you're trying to do (hover on header to transition the other items).

Link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YNXNLN

To fix the vertical center alignment on firefox, add this style (I mean merge, since you already use transform attribute):

```
a {
 transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

But then it will be positioned at the very top on Chrome, so you'll add this style to fix it:

```
a {
 top: 50%;
}
```

Same will be done with horizontal alignment "left: 50%" and you already use translateX, so the value will be up to you.

Comment: It just works, basically ... Thanks for answer!

But in post I wrote that the transform will be used in the animation. I want set by default, the elements were in the center of header. When you hover header, should be the emergence of transition animation category from the center of the header.

Comment: But actially no, it's not what i looking for...  [Link](http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2017/01/06/0001/0403/94611/11/f77698cfb3.png)

Comment: This is definitely what I wanted. Thank you so much! It works like on Chrome, and in Firefox.
But honestly, I also [decided](http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2017/01/06/0001/0403/94611/11/c982533d97.png)  my problem, and it is without flex. :D Later I will add my decision in the answers, too.

Comment: I agree, flexbox is very useful but it's better not to mix it with absolute positioning.