# Flexbox justify-content: center not working properly in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

I'm having trouble getting flexbox and `justify-content: center` to play nicely in Safari.

HTML:

```
<div class="flex-row">
  <div class="label"> Label </div>
  <div class="well"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.well {
  width: 230px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.label {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -8px;
}
```

In Chrome and FF this gives a simple grey well, with a label centered above it. In Safari however the label does not center. Open the CodePen example below in Safari to see the uncentered label:

https://codepen.io/jklevin/pen/weLvxx

My hunch is that this is due to an implementation bug in Safari, but curious if anyone knows of an existing workaround.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32991051/3597276

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`absolute` positioning is not formally supported by flexbox, though it may work in some browsers.

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#abspos-items

> As it is out-of-flow, an absolutely-positioned child of a flex container does not participate in flex layout.

If you want it horizontally centered, just add a `left` and use `transform: translate()` to move it back 50% of it's own width, and you can use that to move it up 8px, too.

```css
.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.well {
  width: 230px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.label {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-8px);
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-row">
  <div class="label"> Label </div>
  <div class="well"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly.

Comment: Actually, this works quite well if this is the only element on the page, but what if I wanted to build this Well as an independent reusable component, and have a number of them within a single row? Using `left: 50%` will mean all of the labels within a row of wells will stack. See:

https://codepen.io/jklevin/pen/weLvxx

Comment: @jklevin you're welcome. you can do that a bunch of ways, I would do it like this https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/Kqjwxz

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the help!