# How to center fixed content in flexbox container in Safari?

Tags: css, safari, flexbox, css-position

[Following code](https://codepen.io/shabunc/pen/KvaYer) works as expected (block is centered) in Chrome and Firefox but in Safari child container is slightly off:

```
#container {
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#content {
   padding: 0px;
  background: linen;
  position: fixed;
}
```

[image]
[image]

My question would be - how to center "position: fixed" element in a "display: flexbox" parent in Safari?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Element with `position: fixed` (or `position: absolute`) won't behave in the same way in Safari as they do in Chrome/Firefox.

To center a flex item in Safari you need to use `transform: translate`

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XaMrvg)

Stack snippet

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#content {
  padding: 0px;
  background: linen;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">THIS CONTENT IS NOT CENTERED IN SAFARI</div>
</div>
```

Comment: yep, this looks like the cheapest valid solution. I wonder though why this differs in Safari and Chrome - is it intentional (like interpreting some CSS spec differently) or just a bug.

Comment: @shabunc It is a changed made in the Flexbox model, where some browsers still haven't catch'd up yet. Here is a thorough explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32991051/absolutely-positioned-flex-item-is-not-removed-from-normal-flow-in-firefox-ie1 ... which might as well qualify as a duplicate