# css: align-items center (flexbox) visual bug in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, flexbox

I'm facing a specific problem when using flexbox and align-items in an element and then absolute positioning in the child.

There's a visual bug in the child element. In firefox, the `<h3>` element —inside `figure.right`— appears at the top of the parent, whether in chromium, the same element appears in the middle of the parent. In firefox, it corrects itself if I **deselect/select** whatever style in the inspector or **resize the window**, so it seems when firefox refreshes the dom, the bug is fixed by itself.

I have the following flexbox element:

```
<figure class="right">
    <h3><?= $lang->getW('h3_a_security') ?></h3>
    <figcaption>
        <p><?= $lang->getW('p_a_security') ?></p>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

And the CSS:

```
* { position: relative; margin: 0; padding: 0 }

figure {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 1vw
}
figure > h3,
figure > figcaption { width: 42.5% }
figure.left > h3 { text-align: right }
figure.right > h3 { position: absolute; right: 0; text-align: left }
figure > figcaption {
    padding: 1vw;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px rgba(230,230,230,0.6);
}
figure.left > figcaption { margin-left: auto }
```

This alone doesn't trigger the bug, but it's basically what I want to achieve. Anyways I've prepared a fiddle, with the full structure where the above code belongs, that demonstrates the bug in firefox: https://jsfiddle.net/cng5z8km/2/ (just resize the output window to see)

Please, confirm it's happening to you too, and if possible, how can I workaround this? Also, how should this be reported? I mean, what is the technical explanation of this bug? I'd like to report it to the bug-tracker but I have no idea how to present it (I suppose it's not appropriate to ask this question as is in the bug-tracker).

[image]

Comment: I don't see any difference in the layout between Chrome and FF. The version of FF you're using may be making a difference.

Comment: Consider that children of a flex container, when absolutely positioned, are *not* flex items. They don't participate in flex layout. Also note that different browsers may vary in their rendering of these absolutely-positioned children. https://stackoverflow.com/q/32991051/3597276

Comment: You sure? I can see the problem in my phone using firefox. In chromium the `<h3>` inside `figure.right` is vertically centered, wether in firefox is at the top. In firefox, when I resize the window, the `<h3>` it falls to the middle automatically.

Comment: I don't see any difference on PC desktop Chrome and FF. However, you may want to consider describing the bug. Your question doesn't really provide a description of the problem, aside from calling it a "visual bug".

Comment: You're right, sorry, I'll edit right away. But I just did explain it, in firefox, the `<h3>` appears at the top of the parent, whether in chromium it is at the middle.

Comment: `h3`s positioned identically for me in Chrome and FF. See the link I posted in my previous comment (read the comments in my answer, as well).

Comment: I just made a gif, so it seems is a problem with my firefox? And with my android firefox too?

Comment: The GIF illustrates the problem well. It's not happening here in FF. Again, FF and Chrome behave the same at all times. Maybe updated to the most current FF??

Comment: I just tried cleaning the cache and site preferences but nothing, even on private mode. I'll save the passwords and try switching to normal firefox, I'm currently using firefox-kde (the one that came installed). But I'll do it tomorrow, it's almost 4am.

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update Sep. 2022**

A note, as of today this might not be an issue anymore, as browsers over time tends to comply with the current spec. in the same way.

So this workaround might, or might not, be needed, other than in situations where one need to support older browsers that still behave differently.

Here is another later posted question, with similar issue and other possible workarounds:

- [Absolutely positioned flex item is not removed from the normal flow in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32991051/absolutely-positioned-flex-item-is-not-removed-from-the-normal-flow-in-ie11)

---

When you make a flex item position absolute, you will encounter different behavior cross browsers since they are not consistent (i.e. in Safari it won't work the same as in Chrome).

- https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/06/absolute-positioned-children

What is seen in your image animation I can't reproduce, thought one way to make an absolute positioned item center vertically cross browser is to use `top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%)`.

```
figure.right > h3 { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;                                /*  added  */
  transform: translateY(-50%);             /*  added  */
  right: 0;
  text-align: left 
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cng5z8km/3/)

Comment: the transform solution does not work in all scenarios and is not a true replacement of the functionality that firefox does not have

Comment: @JohnMiller
 -- 1. I updated my answer to be more clear, and linked to a later post.
 -- 2. No where did I say, or implied, it were a true replacement, workarounds almost never are.

Answer (score 0):

When you have an absolutely positioned element, its parent element needs to have `position:relative;` in order to function as an anchor for the absolutely positioned element. So in your code above, `figure.left` would need `position:relative;` for `figure.right > h3 { position: absolute; right: 0; text-align: left }` to properly work.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention it, I already set `position:relative;` by default at the beginning of the css file. You can see it in the fiddle.

Comment: Also, I changed some style and since then the bug can't be seen. Just adding text so it has height and you can see it: https://jsfiddle.net/cng5z8km/2/